# Problems with content provider (video and photo)

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

Hi I'm try to save different files with `ContentProvider` (videos and photos).But I don't know how to do it in the same class.
I try to do this...

```
public class MyFileContentProvider extends ContentProvider {

    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://com.renata.ideary/picture");
    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI_2 = Uri.parse("content://com.renata.ideary/video");

    private static final HashMap<String, String> MIME_TYPES = new HashMap<String, String>();
    private static final HashMap<String, String> MIME_TYPES_2= new HashMap<String, String>();

    static {

        MIME_TYPES.put(".jpg", "image/jpeg");

        MIME_TYPES.put(".jpeg", "image/jpeg");

        MIME_TYPES_2.put(".mp4","video/mp4");

    }

    @Override

    public boolean onCreate() {

        try {

            File mFile = new File(getContext().getFilesDir(), "/picture.jpg");

            if(!mFile.exists()) {

                mFile.createNewFile();

            }
            File mFile2 = new File(getContext().getFilesDir(), "/video.mp4");

            if(!mFile2.exists()) {

                mFile2.createNewFile();

            }

            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(CONTENT_URI, null);
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(CONTENT_URI_2, null);
            return (true);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

            return false;

        }

    }

    @Override

    public String getType(Uri uri) {

        String path = uri.toString();

        for (String extension : MIME_TYPES.keySet()) {

            if (path.endsWith(extension)) {

                return (MIME_TYPES.get(extension));

            }

        }
        for (String extension : MIME_TYPES_2.keySet()) {

            if (path.endsWith(extension)) {

                return (MIME_TYPES_2.get(extension));

            }

        }
        return (null);

    }

    @Override

    public ParcelFileDescriptor openFile(Uri uri, String mode)

    throws FileNotFoundException {

        if (uri.equals(CONTENT_URI)) {
            File f = new File(getContext().getFilesDir(), "/picture.jpg");

            if (f.exists()) {

                return (ParcelFileDescriptor.open(f,

                        ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_WRITE));

            }

            throw new FileNotFoundException(uri.getPath());
        }
        else {
            File f2 = new File(getContext().getFilesDir(), "/video.mp4");

            if (f2.exists()) {

                return (ParcelFileDescriptor.open(f2,

                        ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_WRITE));

            }

            throw new FileNotFoundException(uri.getPath());
        }
    }

    @Override

    public Cursor query(Uri url, String[] projection, String selection,

                        String[] selectionArgs, String sort) {

        throw new RuntimeException("Operation not supported");

    }

    @Override

    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues initialValues) {

        throw new RuntimeException("Operation not supported");

    }

    @Override

    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String where,

            String[] whereArgs) {

        throw new RuntimeException("Operation not supported");

    }

    @Override

    public int delete(Uri uri, String where, String[] whereArgs) {

        throw new RuntimeException("Operation not supported");

    }

}
```

But always told me the same error:

> 05-06 22:42:37.932 21837-21849/com.renata.ideary E/JavaBinder: *** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)
>                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Operation not supported
>                                                                      at com.renata.ideary.MyFileContentProvider.query(MyFileContentProvider.java:137)
>                                                                      at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:980)
>                                                                      at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:213)
>                                                                      at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:112)
>                                                                      at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)

Someone can help me? Thanks

PD: Save my video but with that error :(